# Can I unlock an iCloud ipod that I bought and no code

Tags: icloud

i need to buy new ipod 5th gen. I keep seeing that many of them are iCloud locked. Can this lock be removed and how do I do it?

Comment: @IconDaemon I don't think this a duplicate of that post.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is **absolutely** no way to bypass the iCloud lock. Usually the only reason it's on is because the iPod was stolen, that's really the whole point of iCloud lock---even if a thief stole your Apple product, he wouldn't be able to get your data off of it and he wouldn't be able to use it after stealing it.

**DO NOT** buy one as it would be about a useful as a brick to you.